Tkinter AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'
I'm trying to plot signals picked up from a microcontroller. I've had problems with port names and now I have this problem that I simply cannot find a solution to.
The widget pops up but the csv file is empty and there is no data being plotted. It is only when I close the graph window that it shows the error.
Widget
Here is the full error message:
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 864, in callit
    self.deletecommand(name)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/tkinter/__init__.py", line 697, in deletecommand
    self._tclCommands.remove(name)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove'

And this is the part of the code which probably contains the problem:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Window
    root.title('XXX')
    root.geometry('500x250')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    # Widget
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Start', width=6, height=4, font=('Arial', 25),\
                     cursor='hand2', bg='gray', command=lambda: main(button1))
    button1.pack(padx=20, pady=0, side=tk.RIGHT)

    label1 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='')
    label1.place(x=20, y=140)

    label2 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='　　  COM：')
    label2.place(x=20, y=40)

    label3 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='')
    label3.place(x=20, y=180)

    entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('Arial', 15), width=3)
    entry.place(x=140, y=40)
    entry.insert(tk.END, '128')

    root.mainloop()

I thought the issue was the way the 'main' function was being called as the command for the button.
I have tried command = main, command = main(), command=lambda: main(button1) and I still get the same problem.
Edit: this is the entire code. The whole processing part comes from Github.
import tkinter as tk
import os
import logging
import threading
import serial
import serial.tools.list_ports
import datetime
import time
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
""" -------------------------- Processing -------------------------"""
"""
Plot live data from serial port using Python, matplotlib and PySerial
Refered from https://github.com/aerialist/serial_plotter/blob/main/serial_plotter.py
"""

class DataWorker(threading.Thread):
    """
    Worker to get date from serial, parse data and put into numpy array
    """
    def __init__(self, ser, data):
        """
        ser: PySerial object
        data: Numpy array to hold data
        """
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self._data = data
        self._ser = ser
        self._running = False
        self._lock = threading.Lock()
        self.logger = logging.getLogger("serial_plotter")

    def stop(self):
        self._running = False

    @property
    def snapshot(self):
        """ make a copy of current data and return
        """
        with self._lock:
            data = self._data
        return data

    def run(self):
        """
        Worker loop
        """
        self.logger.debug("Start running worker")
        self._running = True
        line = ""
        while self._running:
            try:
                if self._ser.is_open:
                    line = self._ser.readline()
            except Exception as e:
                self.logger.exception("Serial port Exception")
            if line:
                line2 = line.decode("utf-8").strip()
                self.logger.info(f'{line2}')
                if line2 == '':
                    #self.logger.info("Emtpy line")
                    pass
                elif line2.startswith('#'):
                    self.logger.info(f"Found comment line: {line2}")
                else:
                    self.parseLine(line2)
        self.logger.debug("Finished running worker")

    def parseLine(self, line):
        """
        Implement your line parsing code here
        This example expects all comma separated values are float
        """
        try:
            # print(line)
            values = [int(line[i*5:(i+1)*5]) for i in range(4)]
            # print(self._data)
            # print(values)
            # make sure the number of values are same as expected
            if len(values) == self._data.shape[0]:
                with self._lock:
                    self._data = np.roll(self._data, -1) # move all data to left by 1
                    self._data[:,-1] = values # replace last data with new values
            else:
                self.logger.error(f"Wrong number of values: {line}")
        except Exception as e:
            self.logger.exception("Exception in parsing")
            self.logger.error(f'{line}')


class Plotter():
    """
    Class to hold plot figure
    provides functions for animation
    """
    def __init__(self, fig, ax, x_data, data_worker):
        """
        fig: Figure
        ax: Axes
        x_data: array of x values
        data_worker: instance of DataWorker that provide data
        """
        self._x_data = x_data
        self.data_worker = data_worker
        self.fig = fig
        self.ax = ax

    def initial_plot(self):
        """
        Adjust plot command
        Make sure to return lines to update
        """
        # obtain latest data from worker
        data = self.data_worker.snapshot
        # draw a line with 1st row data
        self.lineBlue, = self.ax.plot(self._x_data, np.ravel(np.array(data).T), color='tab:blue', linewidth=1.0)
        self.lineRed, = self.ax.plot(self._x_data, np.ravel(np.array(data).T), color='tab:red', linewidth=1.0)
        # adjust plot
        self.ax.set_xlim(0, 1000)
        self.ax.set_ylim(0,2**14)
        return self.lineBlue, self.lineRed,

    def update_plot1(self, frame):
        # obtain latest data from worker
        data = self.data_worker.snapshot
        # update line's ydata
        self.lineBlue.set_ydata(np.append(np.ravel(np.array(data)[1::2].T), np.zeros(1000)))
        return self.lineBlue,

    def update_plot2(self, frame):
        # obtain latest data from worker
        data = self.data_worker.snapshot
        # update line's ydata
        self.lineRed.set_ydata(np.append(np.ravel(np.array(data)[0::2].T), np.zeros(1000)))
        return self.lineRed,

def check_port():
    correct_port = None
    correct_baudrate = False

    ports = list(serial.tools.list_ports.comports())
    print("Available Ports:")
    for p in ports:
        print(p.device)
        if p.device == '/dev/cu.usbmodem1101':
            correct_port = p.device

            ser = serial.Serial(p.device, 115200, timeout=1)
            if ser.baudrate == 115200:
                correct_baudrate = True
            ser.close()
            break

    return correct_port, correct_baudrate

def main(button1):
    correct_port, correct_baudrate = check_port()
    if correct_port is not None and correct_baudrate:
        start_time = time.time() 
        button1['text'] = 'working'
        button1['state'] = 'disabled'
        comport = entry.get()
        dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
        identifier = str(dt_now.month) + '_' + str(dt_now.day) + '_' + str(dt_now.hour) + '_' + str(dt_now.minute) + '_' + str(dt_now.second)
        if not os.path.exists('csv'):
            os.makedirs('csv')
        log_file_name = "csv\\" + identifier + ".csv"
    
        date_fmt = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" 
        format = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s.%(msecs)03d,%(message)s", datefmt=date_fmt)
    
        stream_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
        file_handler = logging.FileHandler(log_file_name)
        stream_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        file_handler.setLevel(logging.INFO)
        stream_handler.setFormatter(format)
        file_handler.setFormatter(format)
    
        root_logger = logging.getLogger()
        root_logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)
  
        logger = logging.getLogger("serial_plotter")
        logger.addHandler(stream_handler)
        logger.addHandler(file_handler)

        port = correct_port
        ser = serial.Serial(port,timeout=1)

        n_values = 4 # expecting number of values in a line
        n_points = 500 # number of latest data points to hold
   
        arr = np.empty(n_values * n_points)
        arr[:] = np.nan
        data = np.reshape(arr, (n_values, n_points))

        arr_x = np.arange(n_values*n_points)

        fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
        axs = [fig.add_subplot(211), fig.add_subplot(212)]

        dataworker = DataWorker(ser, data)
        axs[0].set_ylabel('Acceleration')
        axs[1].set_ylabel('Body conducted sound')

        plotter1 = Plotter(fig, axs[0], arr_x, dataworker)
        plotter2 = Plotter(fig, axs[1], arr_x, dataworker)
        dataworker.start()
        ani1 = FuncAnimation(plotter1.fig, 
                            plotter1.update_plot1, 
                            frames=None,
                            init_func=plotter1.initial_plot, 
                            blit=True, 
                            interval=50,
                            cache_frame_data=False
                            )
        ani2 = FuncAnimation(plotter2.fig, 
                            plotter2.update_plot2, 
                            frames=None,
                            init_func=plotter2.initial_plot, 
                            blit=True, 
                            interval=50,
                            cache_frame_data=False
                            )
        plt.show()
        dataworker.stop()
        elapsed_time = str(int(time.time() - start_time))
        button1['text'] = 'Finished'
        label1['text'] = 'File name：' + identifier + '.csv'
        label3['text'] = 'Time of measurement：' + elapsed_time + ' seconds'
    else:
        button1['text'] = 'Error'
        button1['state'] = 'disabled'
        if correct_port == None:
            label1['text'] = 'correct_port is None'
        elif correct_baudrate == False:
            label1['text'] = 'correct_baudrate = False'

""" ----------------------------- GUI -----------------------------"""


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tk.Tk()

    # Window
    root.title('XXX')
    root.geometry('500x250')
    root.resizable(False, False)

    # Widget
    button1 = tk.Button(root, text='Start', width=6, height=4, font=('Arial', 25),\
                     cursor='hand2', bg='gray', command=lambda: main(button1))
    button1.pack(padx=20, pady=0, side=tk.RIGHT)

    label1 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='')
    label1.place(x=20, y=140)

    label2 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='　　  COM：')
    label2.place(x=20, y=40)

    label3 = tk.Label(root, font=('Arial', 15), text='')
    label3.place(x=20, y=180)

    entry = tk.Entry(root, font=('Arial', 15), width=3)
    entry.place(x=140, y=40)
    entry.insert(tk.END, '128')

    root.mainloop()


Post the function main() as you think it is the cause of the issue.

I added the main function.

Without your setup and given the provided information I was not able to reproduce the error. Could you please specify when the error occurs (is it on button press or when closing the plot window?) and ensure that the traceback is complete. The traceback states, that some object of your gui should be deleted but is None.

There are missing parts.  It is better to provide a [mre] and the full error traceback.

I am still in need of help. Does anybody have an idea to solve the problem?
